# Encountering 'Invalid metadata blob' when I want to backup data?

Tags: influxdb

those is what happened when I wanna backup some data from influxdb:

> [root@bj-collection-01 opt]# influxd backup -database cliReport -host localhost:8086 /opt/clireportbak/ 
>   2018/04/16 10:17:12 backing up metastore to /opt/clireportbak/meta.00 
>   2018/04/16 10:17:12 Invalid metadata blob, ensure the metadata service is running >(default port 8088) 
>   backup: invalid metadata received

but,when I type *netstat -ntlp*,I found:

> tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8088              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      13782/influxd

Comment: backup works if I omit -host,thanks inwi.But,What If my influxdb didnot run on default port?

Comment: You have to expose the RPC port for backups: `8088`. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/administration/config/#bind-address-127-0-0-1-8088). I found it most convenient to use the env var `INFLUXDB_BIND_ADDRESS` for that. Note: you have to open that port additionally to the regular api port `8086`! You can then use that additional port (`8088`) for remote backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you try to use `>localhost:8086` as your host parameter? Then that `>` might be the error. 
On a remote connection, I'm encountering the same error! But from the machine running influxdb it works if I omit the `-host` parameter.

Comment: In order to back it up remotely, use a INFLUXDB_BIND_ADDRESS  of `0.0.0.0:8088` instead of `localhost:8088` or `127.0.0.1:8088`